# Use of closed-source library in LGPL library

Tags: lgpl, closed-source

I would like to open source my software library under the LGPL license. But I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use that license, as my library uses another library which is currently closed sourced. By using I mean that my library has a dependency on that closed sourced, third-party library. I won't be able to distribute the third-party library, but I hope that they will open source it some time later.

What am I allowed to do in this case?

Comment: This may be perfectly fine, or may require you to add an exception to the LGPL. If you need to add an exception, you will not be able to use other LGPL-licensed code in your library. Could you explain a bit more how the proprietary library is used, and how users might obtain it?

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? Are you going to distribute the closed source library too? As an example, many (most) LGPL libraries designed to be used on Windows *use* closed source libraries from Microsoft, but they don't distribute these.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added some more information on my post. Do these answer your questions?

Comment: 1. Which version of the LGPL do you want to use (v2, v3). 2. Do you think the library you want to link to could be considered a "system library"?  See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#SystemLibraryException

Comment: Another possibility is if you consider this closed source library a plug-in or not. The GPL FAQ describes your situation as a "borderline case", assuming you try to consider the library and your library to be separate programs not creating a combined work: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLPlugins

Comment: What are the permissions on that third party library?  Your library is your library, so you are generally free to license it how you want, but the practical problem is this scenario: 1 - Someone gets your library source code (call it "A"). You give users permission to redistribute binary versions of A by some license (e.g. LGPL). 2 - The user builds your source code into a binary (call this "B"). 3 - How would he be able to distribute B to anyone else if he also must distribute an extra library "C" for which he has no permission to redistribute?

Comment: @Brandin and yet again, I think you've pretty much summarised the issue: the OP can do it, but why on earth would (s)he?  Please, write that up as an answer, so I can upvote it, and it can (hopefully) get accepted and put the question to bed.

Comment: @MadHatter is it really possible? I just read: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLIncompatibleLibs and I don't know how to interpret that.
I'm aware that an external person cannot yet use my library, but I hope that I get the owner of the linked library to open source it some time later. Until then it is just good for others to learn (and for my CV :).

Comment: @Brandin I want to use the LGPLv3. I just googled a bit, but I don't understand the definition of a system library. Can you please help me there?

Comment: @JoLau you're proposing to use LGPL, not GPL, so the FAQ you quote doesn't apply.

Comment: @JoLau: A "system library" is essentially a library that can reasonable be expected to be already present on the system of the people that receive your library.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the license under which you got the closed source forbids such use.

Depending on the exact relationship of your code and said library, it might fall under "mere use" of it (in which case it would be OK) or some more intimate relation (in which case you would have to distribute the closed part as LGPL too).

Note that I don't know full details, I'm not your lawyer, so take this as a guess and encouragement to look further into the matter.